# Como fazer download de dados no firebase pelo storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Eu recorri a documentação disponibilizada pelo Firebase e mesmo assim não entendi como faço download de um arquivo que esteja no Storage pelo meu app.

Answer (score -1):

Use uma biblioteca que já vem com o Firebse storage.
No seu build.gradle adicione a linha abaixo em dependencies para poder usar esse recurso do firebase:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
```

Depois crie referência para o arquivo que quer transferir e faça o download usando a biblioteca Glide.
Será feito o download e armazenado em cache.

O exemplo abaixo baixa uma foto e carrega em um ImageView:

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(imagemRef)
        .into(imageView)
```